# found nil in swift while trying to load from Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data

[image]

before code - is for incoming new data 
...

```
else
{
    DispatchQueue.main.async
    {
            let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Identity> = Identity.fetchRequest()
            do {
                self.identities = try DatabaseController.getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)
                for identity in self.identities as [Identity]
                {
                    if identity.id == self.transferedId
                    {
                    //name
                    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = identity.pName
                    self.nameField.text = identity.pName

                    //birth
                    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
                    var dateString = dateFormatter.string(from:identity.birthDate! as Date)
                    self.birthField.text = dateString

                    //modified
                    dateString = dateFormatter.string(from:identity.lastModified! as Date)
                    self.modified.text = "Modified on "+dateString
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                print("Error fetchRequest in ViewWillApper: \(error)")
            }
    }

}
```

...
It doesn't load the window with error.
The problem is - when i try to load this ViewDidAppear ... there is nil error. But separately this code works great on previous VIEW for fetching data. Only when i try to clue them i have an error.

Comment: its not apparent which line of code is causing the crash from what you posted

Comment: Please place breakpoint and debug step by step where actually its crashing

Answer (score 0):

If your context was created in main thread you can’t it use in background and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to be certain since you didn't say which line of code was causing the crash. However "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional" has some common causes. The most likely cause is one of these two lines:

```
var dateString = dateFormatter.string(from:identity.birthDate! as Date)
....
dateString = dateFormatter.string(from:identity.lastModified! as Date)
```

Any time you use a `!` like that in Swift, you are literally saying, if this value is nil, crash the app right here. You're telling Swift to unwrap the optional without checking to see if there's anything to unwrap. So the most likely cause of the crash is that either `birthDate` or `lastModified` is nil, or both.

It might also be that you have implicitly unwrapped optionals in your code that are nil. For example if `self.birthField` or `self.modified` are nil, your code will crash when you try to use them.

This doesn't look like a Core Data problem, it looks like a Swift problem.